# C# StreamReader converts "center text/content" of the string to a three-ellipses "..."

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have a text file containing an HTML codes (saved as UTF-8).

When I try to read the text file using StreamReader (I also tried HtmlDocument.Load()), the content of the file being read seems to be lacking.

And the lacking part is somewhat at the center of the string and replaced with "...".

On the image is a comparison of the string (left side: string read from the StreamReader | right side: string from text file)

[image: string_comparison]

Anyone can help? Thanks.

edit: here is the code:

```
 private Dictionary<string, string> GetSwitzerlandPostalCodes()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string wikipath = Helper.GetWikiPath() + ZipCodeFileName;
        HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        string postalCodeUrl = PostalCodeUrl;
        var path = SaveUrlToText(postalCodeUrl, wikipath);

        htmlDoc.Load(path);  // I also tried to load the path directly and still the OutputHTML or the DocumentNode would contain the ellipses text

        string stringHTML;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) {
            stringHTML = sr.ReadToEnd();  //the stringHTML here would have the ellipses
        }

        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(stringHTML);

        var tableNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='mw-content-text']/table/tr");

        foreach (HtmlNode item in tableNode)
        {
```

Comment: please show us your code

Comment: `StreamReader` wouldn't do this. Show some code and where are the above screenshots from?

Comment: I have added the code guys,

Comment: What tool do you use for displaying the text? I believe it is that tool which creates the ellipses.

Comment: @BernhardHiller I used the Visual Studio 2015 Text Visualizer. I'll check if it has something to do with the Text Visualizer.

Comment: @BernhardHiller I think you're right. I tried to read the file using the StreamReader and write it again on the new file and no data was lost. It was probably on the character limit being displayed on the Text Visualizer. Thanks!